# Finding the maximum and minimum values of $f(x)=|x-1|+|x^2-2x|$ for $x \in [0,2]$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

Can someone help me solve this problem?

> If a function $f(x)$ in the domain $x \in [0,2]$ is
> $$f(x)=|x-1|+|x^2-2x|$$
> then the minimum value is [A] and the maximum one is [B].

I've tried a lot of things:

As I said earlier, I tried to set everything to zero.

The first and second part:

$f(0)=|0-1|+|0^2-2(0)|=>0-1+0^2-2(0)=>f(0)=-1$

$f(2)=|2-1|+|2^2-2(2)|=>2-1+2^2-2(2)=>f(2)=1$

Only the first part:

$f(0)=|0-1|=>0-1=>f(0)=-1$

$f(0)=|0^2-2(0)|=>0^2-2(0)=>f(0)=0$

Only the second part:

$f(2)=|2-1|=>2-1=>f(2)=1$

$f(2)=|2^2-2(2)|=>2^2-2(2)=>f(2)=0$

In all cases, I don't know what to do next. I also tried to do the same thing this guy in this video did (first problem) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3wrXDw5ETh4&t=131s

$\frac{d}{dx}(x-1+x^2-2x)=>-1+2x=0=>x=\frac{1}{2}$

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline X & Y \\ \hline 0 & -1 \\ \hline \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{11}{4} \\ \hline 2 & 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}

But $-\frac{11}{4}$ and $1$ are not the minimum and maximun respectively.

One way this site ([https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Maximum-or-Minimum-Value-of-a-Quadratic-Function-Easily#:~:text=Categories%3A%20Algebra-,To%20find%20the%20maximum%20or%20minimum%20value%20of%20a%20quadratic,%5E2%20%2B%205x%20%2B%204.](https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Maximum-or-Minimum-Value-of-a-Quadratic-Function-Easily#:%7E:text=Categories%3A%20Algebra-,To%20find%20the%20maximum%20or%20minimum%20value%20of%20a%20quadratic,%5E2%20%2B%205x%20%2B%204.)) says you can find the minimum and maximum value of a quadratic equation is by taking the derivative of that equation in its general form.

$f(x)=|x-1|+|x^2-2x|$

$f(x)=x-1+x^2-2x=x^2-x-1$

$f'(x)=2x−1$

$0=2x-1$

$x=\frac{1}{2}$

$f(\frac{1}{2})=|(\frac{1}{2})-1|+|(\frac{1}{2})^2-2(\frac{1}{2})|=\frac{5}{4}$

Which is one of the answers on the answer sheet, $\frac{5}{4}$ is the maximum value, but the minimum value is 1 and not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: @zpearce There is nothing about it in the question, I only now the two answers. A is 1 and B is 5/4.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: @Shaun I've tried a lot of things, I've tried to equalize everything to zero, I've tried to equalize some parts to zero, I've tried to put the domains like functions, I've tried derive the equation, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: One way to deal with absolute value functions is to turn them into peicewise functions.

Comment: rather than describing what you did, just include what you did in your post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a hint rather than a full solution.So this is how I would go about it.

We start by getting rid of modulus symbol

**Case 1:** $0\leq x<1$

$f(x)=-(x-1)+x(-(x-2))=-x^2+x+1=\frac{5}{4}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2$

**Case 2**: $1\leq x\leq 2$

$f(x)=(x-1)+x(-(x-2))=-x^2+3x-1=\frac{5}{4}-(x-\frac{3}{2})^2$

Comment: This is where I took the problem (https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/assets/pdf/plan/questions/16/ga_math_a.pdf), first page, number 1-4, I already know the answers (from the answer sheet https://www.studyinjapan.go.jp/ja/assets/pdf/plan/questions/16/ga_math_a_ans.pdf) but I want to know how to solve the problem, in case something like this falls on another test. 

I don't know if I have permission to post links.